# Why does this combination of ROWNUM<=, left outer join and sub queries sometimes give null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an auto generated SQL that is similar to the below, I have tried to simplify it a bit to demonstrate the crux of the issue I'm facing. Customer.Id is a VARCHAR2(40 byte) and Order.CustomerId is a Number(10,0)

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT query.*, ROWNUM ROWNUM__
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT cst.name, cst.lastname, ord.product, ord.price
        FROM Customer cst
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Order ord ON ord.Manufacturer = 'Samsung'
        AND TO_CHAR(cst.Id) = TO_CHAR(ord.CUSTOMER_ID)
    ) query
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000
)
WHERE ROWNUM__ > 0
```

When I run the innermost query by itself, I get the results i'm expecting, but the problem i'm having is that when running everything together, the LEFT OUTER JOIN is returning null columns. If I remove the below 'where clause' then it works, but unfortunately the paging functionality is handled by the library my workplace built and its use is mandated and so changing those ROWNUM criteria is not an option for me.

```
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000
```

If I remove this then it works, but I need to be able to join by the ID of the table.

```
TO_CHAR(cst.Id) = TO_CHAR(ord.CUSTOMER_ID)
```

If it helps, the execution plan is:

[image]

Comment: Standard behaviour of OUTER JOIN is to return null columns where the join criteria doesn't match. You are choosing first 1000 rows, but didn't sort it in the first place, so you are basically pulling arbitrary rows. You most likely need to add an ORDER BY clause in the inner select query to sort the output if you really need those records that match in Order table, or switch to INNER JOIN perhaps?

Comment: Provide insert scripts as well, this working fine when I mock the data.